# Python and Pandas - Moving Average Crossover

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

There is a Pandas DataFrame object with some stock data. SMAs are moving averages calculated from previous 45/15 days.

```
Date      Price   SMA_45      SMA_15
20150127  102.75  113         106
20150128  103.05  100         106
20150129  105.10  112         105
20150130  105.35  111         105
20150202  107.15  111         105
20150203  111.95  110         105
20150204  111.90  110         106
```

I want to find all dates, when SMA_15 and SMA_45 intersect.

Can it be done efficiently using Pandas or Numpy? How?

**EDIT:**

What I mean by 'intersection':

The data row, when:

- long SMA(45) value was bigger than short SMA(15) value for longer than short SMA period(15) and it became smaller.
- long SMA(45) value was smaller than short SMA(15) value for longer than short SMA period(15) and it became bigger.

Comment: What does it mean for SMA_15 and SMA_45 to intersect on a given date?  (In your example SMA_45 > SMA_15 everywhere, so there doesn't seem to be a good candidate.)

Comment: If by "intersect" you mean where are they the same on the same date then it's a simple matter of using boolean indexing like so, `df[df.sma_15 == df.sma_45]`.

Comment: It's just a piece of data from random stock.

Comment: That didn't really answer @DSM's question. You need to define what you mean by intersect. If you mean set intersection then that would imply that you want all the values that occur in both `SMA_45` and `SMA_15` regardless of them occurring on the same day. Or perhaps you only want an intersection of their values on the same day. Your question as it currently stands introduces too much ambiguity to receive a focused answer.

Comment: @chilliq: that doesn't answer the question.  There are are lots of things you could mean by "intersect": (1) agree (be equal), possibly within some tolerance; (2) 'crossover', as in your question title, in the sense that SMA_45 > SMA_15 is true on one date but SMA_45 < SMA_15 on the next, and so the *lines* intersected; and so on.  Maybe it would help if you showed the *inefficient* way to do this that you had in mind.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm taking a crossover to mean when the SMA lines -- as functions of time --
intersect, as depicted on [this investopedia
page](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sma.asp).

[image]

Since the SMAs represent continuous functions, there is a crossing when,
for a given row, (SMA_15 is less than SMA_45) and (the previous SMA_15 is
greater than the previous SMA_45) -- or vice versa.

In code, that could be expressed as

```
previous_15 = df['SMA_15'].shift(1)
previous_45 = df['SMA_45'].shift(1)
crossing = (((df['SMA_15'] <= df['SMA_45']) & (previous_15 >= previous_45))
            | ((df['SMA_15'] >= df['SMA_45']) & (previous_15 <= previous_45)))
```

If we change your data to

```
Date      Price   SMA_45      SMA_15
20150127  102.75  113         106
20150128  103.05  100         106
20150129  105.10  112         105
20150130  105.35  111         105
20150202  107.15  111         105
20150203  111.95  110         105
20150204  111.90  110         106
```

so that there are crossings,

[image]

then

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
previous_15 = df['SMA_15'].shift(1)
previous_45 = df['SMA_45'].shift(1)
crossing = (((df['SMA_15'] <= df['SMA_45']) & (previous_15 >= previous_45))
            | ((df['SMA_15'] >= df['SMA_45']) & (previous_15 <= previous_45)))
crossing_dates = df.loc[crossing, 'Date']
print(crossing_dates)
```

yields

```
1    20150128
2    20150129
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Little bit late but for the crossover there shouldn't be equal sign on both days: `crossing = (((df['SMA_15']` **<** `df['SMA_45']) & (previous_15 >= previous_45))
            | ((df['SMA_15']` **>** `df['SMA_45']) & (previous_15 <= previous_45)))`

Answer (score 9):

The following methods gives the similar results, but takes less time than the previous methods:

```
df['position'] = df['SMA_15'] > df['SMA_45']
df['pre_position'] = df['position'].shift(1)
df.dropna(inplace=True) # dropping the NaN values
df['crossover'] = np.where(df['position'] == df['pre_position'], False, True)
```

> Time taken for this approach: `2.7 ms ± 310 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`
>
> Time taken for [previous approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28345879/2825570): `3.46 ms ± 307 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu)'s answer, something like below can also be done to find the indices where `SMA_15` crosses `SMA_45`.

```
diff = df['SMA_15'] < df['SMA_45']
diff_forward = diff.shift(1)
crossing = np.where(abs(diff - diff_forward) == 1)[0]
print(crossing)
>>> [1,2]

print(df.iloc[crossing])
>>>
       Date   Price  SMA_15  SMA_45
1  20150128  103.05    100    106
2  20150129  105.10    112    105
```